# JavaFx: webview print with fit to size 100%

Tags: java, javafx

To print my html page I use the following code:

```
  PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
   if (job != null && job.showPrintDialog(null)){
      webView.getEngine().print(job);
      job.endJob();
  }
```

The problem is that webview changes the scale of printing page. For example, when I print this html page in IE with fit to size 100% I get 16.8 cm. When I print in my java application I get 11.4cm. The size in html file I set in pt - my width is 475pt(A4 width=595pt,so 475pt=16.8cm). How to print in webview with fit to size 100%? Is it possible to do?

P.S. If I understand something wrong->I am asking wrong question, please correct me.

Answer (score 2):

There already is a bug report which may be related to your issue.
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8088509
As far as I can tell there is no solution so far.
Michael

Comment: Thank you very much. At lest it's some information. But does it mean that to work with webview printing is impossible? Maybe print nodes? Or what? It's so poweful tool. I don't think there is no any way to use webview and printing...

Comment: Maybe we are talking about different scales? I don't see any scale settings (50%,100% to fit etc) on my PageSetupDialog. I only see 4 options: paper size, portrait vs landscape, paper source, margins.

Comment: The Mac and Windows dialogs may be different. I am on Mac.